# Stretched ends of line with justified alignment in rmarkdown generated MS Word documents

Tags: ms-word, formatting, r-markdown, pandoc

I know how to create a justified alignment Word document from rmarkdown, using a template file. The problem is that the ends of line are all stretched (see picture). In Word, one solves this by putting a tab at the end of the line, but I can't reproduce this in rmarkdown. Adding tabs there doesn't work.

Any solutions that do not involve manual reformatting of all paragraph ends?

[image]

Comment: Not sure whether this works in your case, but have you tried adding a tab using "&#9;"?

Comment: apparently yes! aren't there more evident solution though that an anonymous code?

Comment: So it has worked? If yes. I just figured this out by trial and error, when I had an issue with tabs in Word documents too. Somehow I stumbled over this, but can't remember whether I found it somewhere or ... Most interesting to me is that this works in Word as &#9; is the HTML entity for a tab.

Comment: all the pleasures of MS words... it never stops to amaze me its unpredictability